# Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is this a correct usage of the axiom of choice?

Let $f:B\rightarrow C$ and $g:A\rightarrow B$ be onto, then by definition:
\begin{align*}
&\forall c \in C, \exists b\in B,\text{ s.t. } f(b)=c \ \ \ \text{ and}\\
&\forall b \in B, \exists a\in A,\text{ s.t. } g(a)=b 
\end{align*}
By definition of composition (from Hubbard p.15):
\begin{align*}
(f\circ g)(a)=f[g(a)]
\end{align*}
with domain $A$ and codomain $C$.

By the axiom of choice, every surjection has a right inverse. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists a $b$ such that $f^{-1}(b)=c$. Similarly, $g$ is also surjective, so there exists a $a$ such that $g^{-1}(b)=a$.

Therefore $\forall c \in C,\exists a\in A, \text{ s.t. } f[g(a)]=f(b)=c$.

Comment: Do you even need the axiom of choice to prove that the composition of surjective functions is surjective? In the end, the choice of preimage doesn't need to happen simultaneously, so I guess you could also do it without AoC.

Comment: It's something like saying "since the Axiom of Chhoice is true, we can conclude that $0+0=0$". Ok, this is formally correct, but the Axiom of Choice is totally useless here.

Comment: The "right inverse" of $f$ is $f^{-1}$ not $b$.

Comment: Hi, the requirement is that I need to construct what the definition requires by a procedure that cannot fall: To prove that $h(x)$ is onto, describe a procedure for constructing an $x$ such that $h(x)=y$. The proof consists in showing that this procedure work for all $y$ in the codomain $Y$

Comment: Let $c\in C$ be given. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $b\in B$ such that $f(b)=c.$ Since $g$ is surjective, there exists $a\in A$ such that $g(a)=b.$ Then $f(g(a))=f(b)=c.$ Q.E.D. No right inverses, no Axiom of Choice. Just follow the definitions.

Comment: @bof Not sure. "Describe a procedure for constructing an $x$ ..." Yes,  invoking choice is not much of a procedure, but it very well be the intention of the question.

Comment: hi bof,  that's what i think too, but I am beginner. Do you think the author is trying to be fancy by using axiom of choice?

Comment: @bof: quite so: if you have the time, why don't you write that up into an answer explaining that AC is never required when you only need to choose from a finite number of sets.

Comment: @Cheuk: the suggestion of using the axiom of choice in the proposed argument implies a significant misunderstanding, so don't blindly follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Axiom of Choice is needed if you wish to construct right inverse maps, i.e. maps
$$ \phi_f: C\rightarrow B, \ \ \phi_g: B \rightarrow A$$
with the property that
$$ f \circ \phi_f = 1_C, \ \ g \circ \phi_g = 1_B$$
This follows easily with the AoC but can in general not be done without. If you only want to find inverse images for specific elements this is just set-theory (no need for the AoC).